# First found duplicate element using LINQ (Not contiguous)

Tags: c#

How do I print the **first** duplicate elements from an array?

```
var arr = new int[]{ 3, 2, 5, 1, 5, 4, 2, 15 };
```

Currently this method print 2 instead of 5.

```
 public int FirstDuplicate(int[] arr)
    {
        var firstDup = arr
          .GroupBy(x => x)
          .Where(grp => grp.Count() == 2)
          .Select(grp => grp.Key)
          .FirstOrDefault();

        if (firstDup > 0) return firstDup;

        return -1;

    }
```

Comment: This is because `2` goes earlier then `5` in array. Why should your method return `5` here?

Comment: But the first detected duplicated element is 5

Comment: You have two duplicates in array, `2` and `5`, first `2` is a second element in array, first `5` is third element

Comment: Just for clarification: If the array contains { 2, 5, 3, 5, 2 } what result would you expect? 2, 5 or nothing?

Comment: @SirRufo it seems to be a nothing:)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Steve is the only one who can really answer it - the rest of us can only guess

Comment: @SirRufo OP used the term "contiguous duplicate element" in two places. Hence the answer is obvious (no guess) - there are no **contiguous** duplicate elements in { 2, 5, 3, 5, 2 }.

Comment: @IvanStoev OP **did NOT** used the term - read the history of the question - so which question should we answer here? The question from OP or the modified from Isma?

Comment: I did a rollback of the question - this is the original asked question from the OP

Comment: @SirRufo I see. Yeah, that's weird. I was thinking edits that completely change the meaning of the question are not allowed :-(

Comment: Well, you answered after my edit, so what should not be allowed is to edit the question so it matches your (incorrect) answer even if it was the original OP question.

Comment: actually my original question is not related to contiguous. `5` element can be not contiguous. But since many solutions here are for contiguous, it is okay I can post another question to make it clearer.

Comment: @Isma This is not your question and you should not change the meaning of a question from any other - you can ask your own question with whatever meaning you like

Comment: @pavel, yeah but the first detected duplicate is 5. I know this can be solved with extra space like hashset. Just not sure if it can be solved without extra space with just linq

Comment: @Steve So in your opinion LINQ to Objects method implementations don't use extra space when needed? Of course they do - to name a few: `Join`, `GroupJoin`, `GroupBy`, `Distinct` etc. And they use much more space than the custom method by Sir Rufo. LINQ is *not* for everything.

Answer (score -1):

You can write an extension metod that will return all duplicates from an `IEnumerable<T>` like

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Duplicates<T>( this IEnumerable<T> source )
    {
        var hashset = new HashSet<T>();
        foreach ( var item in source )
        {
            if ( hashset.Contains(item) )
                yield return item;
            else
                hashset.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

and then use it

```
var arr = new int[]{ 3, 2, 5, 5, 4, 2, 15 };
var firstDuplicate = arr.Duplicates().First();
```

see [.net fiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7Zpakl)

Comment: Useful extension method, but this does not address them being contiguous.

Comment: @Zer0 It does - try it yourself or just read the code carefully

Comment: It does not.  I can read the code just fine.  `Duplicates` will return `5` for the array `int[] { 5, 2 5 }`

Comment: @Zero This extension method is for **this** question - not another you may have in mind - this method will return from the given array in the question { 5, 2 } as the OP expected

Comment: I don't think you understand the question.  The question is "How do I print the first contiguous duplicate".  This answer does literally nothing to address contiguous elements at all.  Your extension method literally returns all duplicates.

Comment: @Zer0 Did you read the **whole** answer? `arr.Duplicates().First()` - btw surprisingly I wrote that it returns **all duplicates**

Comment: @Zer0 `int[] { 5, 2, 5 }` has only one duplicate, which is `5`. What else are you expect from duplicate?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski The array `int[] { 5, 2, 5 }` has no *contiguous* duplicates.  And yes I understand this code.

Comment: @Zer0 Read the **original** question from the OP (I did a rollback) should now be visible to everyone. The word *contiguous* was **not** from the OP

Comment: Thanks for the HashSet solution. I hope to find a solution with just LINQ and without extra space if possible.

Comment: Why do you test presence with `Contains` and the add the item with `Add`, when you can do both with just `Add`? You do two hash lookups instead of one.

Comment: The current question should match the current answers.  I don't look at question history every time.  That aside, I do agree with @AntonínLejsek and I also suggest using `FirstOrDefault`.  With those changes I'd upvote your answer.  I did note I liked the extension method, just not if the requirement was contiguous duplicates.

Comment: @Zer0 There is a problem with FirstOrDefault. If it returns 0, does it mean, that there is no duplicate value, or does it mean, that the first duplicate value is 0?

Comment: @AntonínLejsek Understood. `Cast(int?).FirstOrDefault()` works off the top of my head.  Just want to avoid an Exception.  Relatively speaking they are very expensive, plus you shouldn't use exceptions as normal control flow.

Comment: @Zer0 I agree with the exceptions and sure, it is solvable. But this is just too easy to be done wrong, have a look at RoadRunner. So I pointed at it.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me. I took advantage of comparing values with array indexes, the `Distinct()` method, and the first element of the resulting array.

```
var arr = new int[] { 3, 2, 5, 5, 4, 2, 15 };
var adjacentDuplicate = arr.Skip(1)     // Skip first
    .Where((value,index) => value == arr[index])
    .Distinct()
    .ToArray();     // Convert to array

if (adjacentDuplicate.Any())
{    
    Console.WriteLine(adjacentDuplicate[0]);    // Print first duplicate
}
else
{
   // No duplicates found.
}
```

Comment: Nice. It works. May I know how's the space and time complexity compare to hashset?

Comment: Beware that `Distinct` is not guaranteed to preserve order.

Answer (score -1):

Based on Sir Rufo answer, I would make two extensions

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Duplicates<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    var hashset = new HashSet<T>();
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        if (!hashset.Add(item))
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }
}

public static IEnumerable<T?> AsNullable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) where T : struct
{
    return source.Select(x => (T?)x);
}
```

You can use it like

```
var duplicate = arr
    .Duplicates()
    .AsNullable()
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

The `AsNullable`converts `int` into `int?` without hard coding the type. When the result is null, there is no duplicity. You can use it in more situations, like calculating the `Max` of potentially empty sequence of non nullable values (you can define it for `IQueryable` too). The advantage of this extension is, that when you use it, you know for sure, that null is not valid value in the source. And you would not shoot yourself into the leg when the null suddenly becomes a possible value.